# Should there be a comma between an independent clause followed by "intent on" + -ing (ex. intent on helping...)

Tags: punctuation, syntax

If there's a sentence beginning with an independent clause and ending with something like "intent on seeing the good in others," how would I punctuate it midway (if at all)?

Ex. We are passionately communicative intent on seeing the good in others.

Is it correct to use a comma? (We are passionately communicative, intent on seeing the good in others.)
Should the em dash be used? (We are passionately communicative—intent on seeing the good in others.)

The second part of the sentence could potentially contain, "and we are" which would make the whole thing a compound sentence requiring a comma. However, with those elements missing, what would you suggest and what would the rationale be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this can depend on what exactly you are writing and on matching your own writing style. Much of punctuation, although purpose built, is more or less to represent pauses and fluctuation in cadence of speech. The more casual the audience, the more leeway you have with punctuation usage. I believe you are correct in the use of a comma from a professional writing standpoint for an important document of some sort. However, if this is being written as a quote, to be read as a speech, or to be spoken by a character in a story, then the em dash might be more appropriate as a means of conveying the length of the pause and emphasizing the last part of the statement. That may be best left to your own personal interpretation though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, this is for an official marketing document, so I want to get it right. I just wish I could justify the comma with an actual structural answer. You and I are on the same wavelength. I'm an em dash fan, but I think it could look a bit clumsy, so perhaps I will stick to the comma then. You're my first ever StackExchange response! Thank you!